# Apache Camel: making a regex work with File2's include filter

Tags: java, regex, apache-camel

I'm using Camel to process files from a directory. However, I want my camel route to only process files whose names match a specific regex pattern. Therefore, I added the `include` option to the `File2` configuration and passed in the required regular expression.

An example of the filename pattern:

```
somerandomname-2017-10-02T13-23-42+02-00.zip
```

The regular expression I came up with:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9_]+\-\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}T\d{2}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\+\d{2}\-\d{2}\.zip$
```

The `File2` component's string I'm passing to `from(...)`:

```
file://...?include=^[A-Za-z0-9_]+\-\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}T\d{2}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\+\d{2}\-\d{2}\.zip$&...
```

However, *all* files are ignored. It works when changing the regular expression to a much simpler one, such as `.*\.zip`, so the problem is definitely related to `include` and my pattern. I also tried it without the start and end operators (`^` and `$`) with no success:

```
.*?[A-Za-z0-9_]+\-\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}T\d{2}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\+\d{2}\-\d{2}\.zip
```

Any help is appreciated.

edit 1: I tested the regex with `String.matches` and `Matcher.matches` (assuming that this is what Camel uses internally) without any problems. I'm using the current Camel version 2.19.3.

edit 2: I tried to find the minimal working pattern, and while `.*?\d{2}\-\d{2}\.zip` still works, `.*?\+\d{2}\-\d{2}\.zip` doesn't. So it seems that it has something to do with the `+` sign.

Comment: The `^` matches the start of a string, remove it from inside the pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew as I wrote above, I already tried it without `^`. I also added a `.*` in front without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using the filter-option instead. That way you eliminate the possibility that your regex gets URL-encoded (which I suspect might be the case).

```
public class MyFilter<T> implements GenericFileFilter<T> {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(GenericFile<T> file) {
        if (file.getFileName().matches("^[A-Za-z0-9_]+\-\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}T\d{2}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\+\d{2}\-\d{2}\.zip$"))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then you could reference your bean in the filter-option like so:

```
<from uri="file:///someDir?filter=#myFilter" />
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Yes, the regex indeed got url encoded, but at first I thought that can't be the problem since this also was the case with the simple regex (which worked).. so url encoding the plus sign seems to cause trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The plus sign `'+'` is replaced by a space `' '`, even if the regex is encoded.

This is used by camel in the quartz2 component where the cron expression is separated by `'+'` : `cron=0/5+*+*+1/1+*+?+*`

The solution is to use `RAW(^myRegex.+$)`